# Can i convert this text "1.72101e+011" to number?

Tags: c#

can i convert this text "1.72101e+011"  to number ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
string val = "1.72101e+011";
decimal d;
Decimal.TryParse(val,NumberStyles.Any,null , out d);
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx) method:

```
string s = "1.72101e+011";
double res;
if (double.TryParse(s, out res))
{
    // use the result
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
double result= Double.Parse("1.72101e+011", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);
```